# Quartz Performance Drawing Large Buffers

Tags: ios, performance, xamarin.ios, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I am wondering if what I'm attempting is just a bad idea. I'm currently working in monotouch. Is it possible to draw a screen-sized (on my iPhone 4 its about 320x460) buffer onto a UIView of equal size fast enough so that animated changes to that buffer look smooth to the end user (need it to be around 20ms per draw).

I've attempted many different implementations. The best one so far seems to be using an in-memory CGLayer and calling context.DrawLayer() to apply it to the view inside of Draw(). But even that takes 30-40ms per DrawLayer.

I'm writing my own tile-image control, and aside from performance, the idea is working well. I just can't figure out how to get the buffer onto the UIView fast enough.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've been dealing with custom views a lot lately, and i've had a bunch of performance problems, too.

All of these performance issues could be solved by determining the elements that need to be redrawn, and, more importantly, the elements that do *not* need to be redrawn.

Then, split the contents in the layer into individual sublayers and only redraw them if necessary. The good thing is, animations and so on are very smooth for those individual layers. (Their content is only a simple bitmap and does not change until you tell it to).

The only limitation i've come across was, that you cannot use CG blend modes (e.g. multiply) for the sublayers. As far as i know that is not possible. You can only use those blend modes inside the CG code used to draw the contents of the sublayers, but after that they are all composed in "normal" mode.

Comment: The only tricky part is that I need the buffer to update constantly. I'm loading in new image tiles (think google maps) all the time, so the buffer changes a lot.

Comment: I see... I am sorry that i cannot really help you with this issue. Another idea: Is your layer significantly larger than the screen? Those were a huge performance hit in my case... Also: are you sure that the drawing routines are the slow part? (and not the code loading the tiles?)

Comment: I think I've found a good balance by using CALayers and loading new buffers in when the user stops moving things around. It definitely seems like drawing the bitmap to a context is always the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you are drawing.

If you are just drawing a solid filled color, that should not be a problem.   The question is how much of the surface you are changing, and how you are changing it.

Again, it depends on what you are drawing and whether you could offload some of the work to the GPU.   For example if you have static parts of your interface that will remain the same, or are animated/updated independently, you could use a different layer for those areas and let the GPU compose those.

Layers have the advantage that they are composited by the GPU, and they are backed by their own bitmaps.   Once you draw into the surface of the layer, the OS will cache the result in the GPU and compose all of your layers at the same time.

Then you can determine which parts of your application actually need to be redrawn and only redraw those sections on each frame.

But again, it really will depend a lot on what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is the approach I've been taking. The problem is that my layer needs to be updated constantly. I'm trying to achieve a look similar to what google maps gets. I haven't figured out how to get that layer/buffer to keep updating and keep performance. If it stays static, then I don't have the problem.